# How to create additional routes in express for application configured for React-Router?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-router

I have to make an API call from my server. It is already configured in a way that every `app.use(/*` will return index.html.

So, now when I create an additional route using `app.get('/info'`, it returns the index.html itself.

How to create new routes. Implementing a separate server and backend seems to be the closest approach. But that seems too much for this simple a task.

Comment: You can use regex routing, but probably is better approach to have a separate service.

Comment: What do you mean by new routes? Routes that should not be handled by React Router?

Comment: yes. I need server to server communication. And to access the results in my frontend I need to define new routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Express, routes are checked in the order that they are registered with the app. Because you have a catch all route (`/*`), anything that you register with the app after assigning that will be matched by the catch all. You should define alternate routes before your catch all.

```
// first
app.get('/info', infoHandler)
// then
app.use('/*', indexHandler)
```